# Clean black & white style for minted

Tags: minted, sourcecode

I'm using `minted` to format code in a book. Except for the `bw` theme, I only see colored styles, which is nice for producing a PDF, but not ideal for printing in black & white.

Is there a clean black & white style I can use (probably something resembling what `algorithmicx` produces) for `pygments`/`minted` which I could use for the printable version of the book?

Comment: You can try `\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}`

Comment: That works @MarcoDaniel, but it doesn't make text bold like `algorithmicx` does.

Comment: The `gray` option prevents other colors to appear. Especially, when highlighting some text (like when using the `changes` package). Using `ulem` instead of colors might not be the best choice: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270901/cleveref-and-ulem-soul-compatibility. I really like the `friendly` style and would love to see it converted to a grayscale style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marco's solution is probably the nicest one:

```
\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}
```

The reason I was not getting bold text was that I only loaded Inconsolata and not Inconsolata Bold. I now set up my mono font like this:

```
\setmonofont[Scale=0.9,BoldFont={Inconsolata Bold}]{Inconsolata}
```

and the result is fine (using the default style):

[image: black and white code listing]

Comment: Help! This is literally the only example of a good gray-scale minted theme I could find on the internet. Can you please share the latex file that produces this output?