# cleveref and ulem/soul compatibility

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, soul, ulem

I'm trying to use `uwave` and `cleveref` together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\uwave{\cref{sec:A}}
\section{A}
\label{sec:A}
\end{document}
```

After calling `pdflatex` twice, I get following output:

> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \UL@stop ...z@ \else \UL@putbox \fi
>   \else \egroup
>                                                     \egroup \UL@putbox \fi \if... l.5 \uwave{\cref{sec:A}}
>
> ?

What am I doing wrong or whom should I ask for a fix?

Similar effect with `soulpos` and `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\hl{\cref{sec:A}}
\section{A}
\label{sec:A}
\end{document}
```

> ! Argument of \cref  has an extra }.
>   
>                   \par
>   l.6 \hl{\cref{sec:A}}
>
> ?

Comment: Off-topic comment: Is it really necessary to use `\uwave` for references?

Comment: It is a MCVE showing as little commands and text as possible. The use case is to track changes in a document. Instead of using the changes package, I use \uwave and \pdfcomment to highlight changes and to explain them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In these cases, add `\mbox` around the offending piece; it works also with `soul`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\uwave{\mbox{\cref{sec:A}}}

\section{A}
\label{sec:A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the record: The box keeps the text together. I've defined a command `\citet` mirroring natbis's command: `\newcommand{\citet}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1}}`. Putting an `mbox` around `\citet` might cause strange layouts. But it's good enough for me...