# newcommand + csname + sout + cref = ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup

Tags: macros, soul, csname

I'm not sure to understand why, but I created a command to automatically add a strike-command per author. If I use it strike normal text, it works. If I use it to strike a text with `\cref{...}` inside, it fails with an error `ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.` (of course I checked that all brackets are closed). I'm not sure why, but everything that strikes fails (ulem, soul) but textcoloring works.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\addEditor}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1Remove\endcsname[1]{%
    \sout{##1}%
  }%
}

\addEditor{myname}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Demo}\label{sec:mysec}
Removing a simple text works: \mynameRemove{See this simple text without cref}.

Removing a text with cref fails: \mynameRemove{See this text with \cref{sec:mysec}}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270901/134574?

Comment: Oh, I think you're right yes, thanks. I was sure that `\sout{\cref{...}}` without the newcommand, but apparently it's not. The only problem of the solution is that I need to ask to all authors to manually write `\mbox{\cref{...}}` around the cref which is not really practical...

Comment: Is there any way to automatically add this surounding \mbox, or to use \mbox that allows multiline text?