# Clean dichromatic style for minted

Tags: minted

Can anyone suggest a `pygments` style for `minted` that looks nice with one color in addition to black (so... two colors in total, hence my interest in a "dichromatic" style)?

This would be useful in a book whose print version doesn't have a full color palette but does have one color, say magenta. I would like to find a readable and appealing style that uses only black and various tints of one specified other color.

[See this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57779/clean-black-white-style-for-minted) about a clean black-and-white `pygments` style.

Comment: The book includes code from a variety of languages.

Comment: Unless I'm really misunderstanding things, a Pygments _style_ is language independent. Keywords, identifiers, comments, etc are each mapped to a typeface and color, and so styles can be paired with lexers for any language.

Comment: See [making your own style](https://pygments.org/docs/styledevelopment/#creating-own-styles).